# GWD Custom component

Tags: google-web-designer

I've created a custom component but the problem is that when I preview or export that component the image aren't exported

```
{
 /* ... */
  "attributes": [
   {
    "name": "bkgmap",
    "label": "bkgmap",
    "type": "string",
    "required": true,
    "description": "desc",
    "gwdSpecific": {
      "label": "bkgmapImg",
      "sync":   "src"
    }
   },
   {
    "name": "bkgback",
    "label": "bkgback",
    "type": "string",
    "required": true,
    "description": "desc",
    "gwdSpecific": {
      "label": "bkgbackImg",
      "sync":   "src"
    }
   },
   {
    "name": "bkgfore",
    "label": "bkgfore",
    "type": "string",
    "required": true,
    "description": "desc",
    "gwdSpecific": {
      "label": "bkgforeImg",
      "sync":   "src"
    }
   },
   {
    "name": "bar",
    "label": "bar",
    "type": "string",
    "required": true,
    "description": "desc",
    "gwdSpecific": {
      "label": "barImg",
      "sync":   "src"
    }
   } /* ... */    
  ],

}
```

In this way, with the sync property I'm able to export only one image, someone know how is it possible to achieve the image inclusion? And also someone know how to set up a file upload type? the attributes type "file" works but isn't possibile to select any file, also if I specify the accept property.

Comment: what you have posted in the question is probably just a json that has a list/array inside it. This is very little info for anyone to help you out. Please supplement your question with relevant chunks of code, together with explanation about what you intended that chunk of code to do, and what it actually did. This way, people would be able to check out your tries and (depending on the coding language), appropriate people would be able to help you out.

Comment: Hi ARD, my code is a piece of the manifest.json the GWD uses to generate the field in the custom module properties. There isn't ohter code involved in this process.

Answer (score 2):

```html
{
      "name": "dragIcon",
      "label": "Drag Icon",
      "type": "file",
      "description": "Choose the images",
      "required": true,
      "accept": "image/*",
      "bindable": false
    },
```